# Symfony 4 - The child node "tag_class" at path "beelab_tag" must be configured

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using Symfony 4 and I have this error after installing Bee-Lab/BeelabTagBundle :

> The child node "tag_class" at path "beelab_tag" must be configured.

It's written in the documentation that we must configure the set in app/config/config.yml but in Symfony 4 this file does not exist anymore.

```
# app/config/config.yml

# BeelabTag Configuration
beelab_tag:
    tag_class: AppBundle\Entity\Tag
    purge:     true
```

How can I configure it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Under config/packages/, create a new file called beelab_tag.yaml

Then put your config in it the same way you did, so :

```
# config/packages/beelab_tag.yaml

# BeelabTag Configuration
beelab_tag:
    tag_class: AppBundle\Entity\Tag
    purge:     true
```

Comment: Thanks :) the file name is based on the key beelab_tag ?

Comment: Indeed, not sure if it's mandatory though, but you can easily find out

Answer (score 0):

Hi Aurelien is it possible to add multiple classes in tag_class I mean like below

```
beelab_tag:
tag_class: [ContactBundle\Entity\Tag, ContactBundle\Entity\Interest]
purge: false
```

tried adding like above not working can you please let me know is there any way we can add multiple tag classes